# Troubleshooting auto vectorize reason '1200'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vectorization, sse

MSVC 2013 Ultimate w/ Update 4

Not understanding why I am getting this error on this seemingly simple example

info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'

which is

1200 Loop contains loop-carried data dependences

I don't see how the iterations of the loop could interfere with each other.

```
__declspec( align( 16 ) ) class PhysicsSystem
{
public:
    static const int32_t MaxEntities = 65535;

    __declspec( align( 16 ) ) struct VectorizedXYZ
    {
        double      mX[ MaxEntities ];
        double      mY[ MaxEntities ];
        double      mZ[ MaxEntities ];

        VectorizedXYZ()
        {
            memset( mX, 0, sizeof( mX ) );
            memset( mY, 0, sizeof( mY ) );
            memset( mZ, 0, sizeof( mZ ) );
        }
    };

    void Update( double dt )
    {
        for ( int32_t i = 0; i < MaxEntities; ++i ) <== 1200
        {
            mTmp.mX[ i ] = mPos.mX[ i ] + mVel.mX[ i ] * dt;
            mTmp.mY[ i ] = mPos.mY[ i ] + mVel.mY[ i ] * dt;
            mTmp.mZ[ i ] = mPos.mZ[ i ] + mVel.mZ[ i ] * dt;
        }
    }

private:    
    VectorizedXYZ   mTmp;
    VectorizedXYZ   mPos;
    VectorizedXYZ   mVel;
};
```

Edit: Judging by http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/05/08/auto-vectorizer-in-visual-studio-11-rules-for-loop-body.aspx this would seem to be an example of "Example 1 – Embarrassingly Parallel", but it acts like it thinks the arrays are unsafe from aliasing, which is puzzling to me.

Edit2: It would be nice if someone could share the reasons why the auto vectorization fails on such a seemingly simple example, but after tinkering with it for some time, I opted instead to take the reigns myself

```
void PhysicsSystem::Update( Real dt )
{
    const __m128d mdt = { dt, dt };

    // advance by 2 since we can do 2 at a time at double precision in __m128d
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < MaxEntities; i += 2 )
    {
        __m128d posX = _mm_load_pd( &mPos.mX[ i ] );
        __m128d posY = _mm_load_pd( &mPos.mY[ i ] );
        __m128d posZ = _mm_load_pd( &mPos.mZ[ i ] );

        __m128d velX = _mm_load_pd( &mVel.mX[ i ] );
        __m128d velY = _mm_load_pd( &mVel.mY[ i ] );
        __m128d velZ = _mm_load_pd( &mVel.mZ[ i ] );

        __m128d velFrameX = _mm_mul_pd( velX, mdt );
        __m128d velFrameY = _mm_mul_pd( velY, mdt );
        __m128d velFrameZ = _mm_mul_pd( velZ, mdt );

        _mm_store_pd( &mPos.mX[ i ], _mm_add_pd( posX, velFrameX ) );
        _mm_store_pd( &mPos.mY[ i ], _mm_add_pd( posX, velFrameY ) );
        _mm_store_pd( &mPos.mZ[ i ], _mm_add_pd( posX, velFrameZ ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Just 2 remarks: 1/ since the update method is inline, when I tried to compile this, nothing was happening which puzzled me for a while; and 2/ now that I un-inlined it, Intel compiler version 15.0.3 just vectorises without any problem.

Comment: Thanks. And interesting. MSVC 2015 doesn't like it either

Comment: I would certainly suggest you looking into portable vectorization (aka using OpenMP 4.0's `#pragma omp simd`). Assuming that you have a compiler that supports it (icc 15+ does, I believe), then it will both make your life a lot easier and also give you control over what is and isn't vectorized. As opposed to just "making suggestions" to the compiler about what should be auto-vectorized.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. Unfortunately I'm stuck in MSVC which is way behind the OMP curve.

Comment: Well, this is ugly (no offence intended)... You should definitely let the compiler do, since 1/ you only vectorise for 128b vector registers whereas 256b are common and 512b ones will soon become; and 2/ you do not take advantage of fused multiply and add which might divide by another two your number of operations (not too sure about that since it depends on whether it's a FMA3 or FMA4 that you have access to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your compiler supports it, but for enforcing some proper vectorisation, you can portably do that:

```
void PhysicsSystem::Update( double dt ) {
    double *tx=mTmp.mX, *ty=mTmp.mY, *tz=mTmp.mZ;
    double *px=mPos.mX, *py=mPos.mY, *pz=mPos.mZ;
    double *vx=mVel.mX, *vy=mVel.mY, *vz=mVel.mZ;
    #pragma omp simd aligned( tx, ty, tz, px, py, pz, vx, vy, vz )
    for ( int i = 0; i < MaxEntities; ++i ) {
        tx[ i ] = px[ i ] + vx[ i ] * dt;
        ty[ i ] = py[ i ] + vy[ i ] * dt;
        tz[ i ] = pz[ i ] + vz[ i ] * dt;
    }
}
```

You need then to enable the OpenMP support for the directive to be taken into account.

Comment: What the heck. If I do all of that but the pragma line then it works.

Comment: I expected it to work even without the pragma, but couldn't check since I don't have your compiler.... The thing is, I guess, that the compiler assumes some possible aliasing of member arrays inside the `VectorizedXYZ` structures. By going back to simple pointers, you break the links between the members...

Comment: Probably using 3 separate loops without the pointer trick would work as well

Comment: I also tried to use naked arrays in the class, such as

`double  mPosX[ MaxEntities ];`

instead of the struct wrapper to no avail

Comment: In case you're not aware Visual Studio only supports OpenMP 2.0 which does not support `omp simd` (but I am not saying the rest of you answer is not useful).

Comment: Then the OP should use `#pragma loop( ivdep )` which seems to be the way Visual Studio C++ 2012 permit to force vectorisation. [See this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh923901%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)